# SQL statement with formula

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write an SQL statement that will calculate the total value of a purchase order.

Example time!

```
SELECT PO_Number, LineItem, Quantity, Cost
FROM POs
```

Say on `PO_Number=484` there are 2 units of `LineItem-1` at $2 each. There are also 3 units of `LineItem-2` at $5 each. Is there a way to output $19? (2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 19)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity*Cost) WHERE PO_Number = 484;
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to show the totals for multiple purchase orders, you need to "group" your results by purchase order:

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity*Cost)
WHERE PO_Number IN (484,485,486) -- if you want specified ones only, omit for all
GROUP BY PO_Number;
```

Comment: Great! Almost there. What if there is more than 1 PO_Number on the table, sometimes dozens.

Answer (score 1):

Or...

SELECT PO_Number, SUM(Quantity*Cost)
GROUP BY PO_Number;